# Redis Cache storing whole objects vs cache models with partial information

Tags: c#, caching, redis, azure-redis-cache

I am using Azure Redis Cache to store objects. Before I save them to the cache im compressing them using MessagePack. My question is, is there a performance loss on retrieving a full object vs retrieving a cache model that has only the properties that are currently used.

The reason I want to store the whole object is to future proof and not have to update the cache models if suddenly a new property is needed. Also using the original class I can use one Core model to interact with the DB and the cache.

My thought is since im  already opening the connection to the cache ive already paid the heavy cost and the transfer itself is negligible with the compressed data. We are talking in the realms of 3-4 KB at the extreme max.

Comment: `My question is, is there a performance loss on retrieving a full object vs retrieving a cache model that has only the properties that are currently used.` What happened when you benchmarked it?

Comment: In your question you mention future proofing, by saving yourself from adding a new property in the future. I'm not sure how that is going to save you changing the model, could you explain? Think of the inverse issue, what if you need to remove an object in the future, have you cached too much? In most cases, you would want to serialize only the properties that cannot be computed. As the network latency increases, the cost of pulling the objects increases, while the ability to compute those properties remains relatively constant.